# Як можна передати українською російське "мелкими перебежками"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, фразеологізми

Як можна передати українською російське *"мелкими перебежками"*?

Тобто, коли через негоду (або за якоїсь іншої причини, наприклад, через те, що доводиться іти назустріч натовпу) треба перебігати від одного місця до іншого, щоб рухатися у потрібному напрямку?

Але, в той самий час (під час дощу) треба перебігати від одного дерева до іншого, а під самими деревами бігти не обов'язково - можна спокійно йти.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Пряме калькування: "короткими [перебіжками](http://sum.in.ua/s/perebizhka)".

> *В тих завіях короткими перебіжками наступала піхота.* — Олесь Гончар. "Прапороносці".
>
> *Короткими перебіжками до мене! Так! Ближче! Щільніше!* — Павло Загребельний. "Юлія або запрошення до самовбивства".
>
> *Фігуро! До компоту й пиріжків! Короткими перебіжками! — вигукував
> Дмитруха і, розштовхуючи всіх, летів у буфет.* — Всеволод Нестайко. "Одиниця з обманом".

Answer (score 20):

1. [куцим](http://sum.in.ua/s/kucyj) [вчухром](http://sum.in.ua/s/chukhraty) / (*суржик:* куцим вшчурхом)
2. [дрібним](http://sum.in.ua/s/dribnyj) [шмигом](http://sum.in.ua/s/shmyghaty)

та інші перестановки

Answer (score 5):

Щойно придумалося ***То бігцем, то стовпцем***.

Але це моє власне, тому без посилань.

І, очевидно, не тотожний відповідник, з огляду на різне стилістичне забарвлення.

Сподобався також варіант *дрібним шмигом*.

Answer (score 0):

***Дрібними кроками* або [копотіти](http://sum.in.ua/s/kopotity)**

КОПОТІТИ, очу, отиш, недок., розм. Стукаючи, тупаючи, іти, **бігти дрібними кроками**.

> *Ой ще зілля не кипить, А вже милий копотить (Павло Чубинський, V, 1874, 417);
>
>   — Діду! Діду! — гукав хлопчик, чимдуж копотячи з гори* (Панас Мирний, I, 1954, 165);
>   *Вони [повстанці] вже переїхали через браму і **копотять** горі дорогою* (Іван Франко, VIII, 1952, 302);

*//  Стукати, тупати, ідучи, **біжачи дрібними кроками**.*

> *Летить наш кінь! Він копитами на цілий всесвіт **копотить**...* (Павло Тичина, II, 1957, 208);
>   *На вулиці Горького чисто, просторо, і ранком в урочистій тиші лиш дзвінко **копотить** чобітками дітвора та підлітки по асфальтових тротуарах* (Народна творчість та етнографія, 2, 1962, 97).

*Швидкими рухами* теж іноді використовую, проте, судячи з прикладів вживання, цей вираз більше використовується для позначенні рухів *частин* тіла - очей, рук, голови, крил тощо:

> Онейрологія — наука, що вивчає сновидіння. Сновидіння вважаються
>   пов'язаними з REM-фазою сну (Rapid eye movement). Ця стадія виникає
>   приблизно кожні 1,5-2 години сну і її тривалість поступово
>   подовжується. Вона характеризується **швидкими рухами очей**, які ніби
>   стежать за переміщеннями об'єктів, стимуляцією Варолієвого мосту,
>   прискореним диханням і пульсом, тимчасовим паралічем тіла.
>
> Під час сну з **швидкими рухами очей** наш високоактивізованний мозок
>   створює сни, які іноді нелогічні і заряджені емоціями (Foulkes, 1962;
>   Hobson, Pace-Schott & Stickgold, 2000).

Comment: -1: це не відповідає російському "мелкими перебежками".

Comment: російське "мелкими перебежками" - це цілком швидко (зазвичай навіть дуже швидко) перебігати від одного "укриття" до іншого з метою дістатися чогось. Мені здається, що в питанні непогано це описано...

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, цитую автора питання "тобто, коли через негоду (**або за якоїсь іншої причини, наприклад через те що доводиться іти назустріч натовпу**) - йти назустріч натовпу не те саме, що "перебігати від одного "укриття" до іншого з метою дістатися чогось".

Comment: @sashaeve Доцитовую: "треба перебігати від одного місця до другого щоб рухатися у потрібному напрямку" І подивіться на оновлення питання. Не ображайтеся, будь ласка. Просто я знаю, що це неправильна відповідь, тому я мушу поставити -1 (хоча це -1 моїй репутації ;) )

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, я не ображаюсь, я запропонував свій варіант. Очевидно, що він може бути помилковим.

Comment: Це навіть не "російське", а радянське військове. Термін міг існувати і до радянських часів, але саме завдяки загальному призову вислів розповсюджений.

Comment: Цікаві/корисні варіанти і аналіз, але це справді, як каже Kyrylo Yatsenko, зовсім інше значення.